# mod_rewrite and subdomains

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I have a "beta" subdomain for testing my actual project, this subdomain is pointing to the `beta` folder in my root server.
I have a `users` folder with all the users information too.

For showing the profile of user 58, currently we need:
`beta.domain.com/users/user58`

But... I want to hide a part of the URL and only show in the address bar the follow:
`beta.domain.com/user58`

In the same way, if I redirect internally to `beta.domain.com/user33`, the address bar will show this URL and the content of `beta.domain.com/users/user33`

I created the follow `.htaccess` file in the `beta` folder of my server.

```
DirectoryIndex default.php index.php index.html index.htm
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/$ users/$1 [L,NC]
```

But nothing happen!!!
I tryed copying the file to the server root with the same result.

Some suggestion, please?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the / at the end of the regular expression.  This would match beta.domain.com/user33/, but not without the /.  Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_]+)$ users/$1 [L,NC]
```

You can always include the / optionally by putting a ? after it: `^([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/?$`

Comment: Thanks Cory, but nothing change without the "/"... for example: I created a botton with the href="beta.domain.com/users/user18", when I clicked it the address bar shows "beta.domain.com/users/user18" instead "beta.domain.com/user18"... if I typed directly in the address bar "beta.domain.com/user18" I received an error of 404 Not Found

Comment: Perhaps you are looking in the wrong place.  Are you sure that the .htaccess file is actually being parsed?  Is "AccessFileName .htaccess" in your apache2.conf or httpd.conf (this is required)?  Do you have "AllowOverride None" set anywhere?